# strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string error on configuration and system status page

Tags: 7

I am getting the following error on the configuration and the system status page:

> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
> _system_sort_requirements() (line 2805 of   /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.module).
>
> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in _system_sort_requirements() (line 2805 of /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.module).
>
> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in _system_sort_requirements() (line 2805 of /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.module).
>
> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in _system_sort_requirements() (line 2805 of /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.module).
>
> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in _system_sort_requirements() (line 2805 of /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.module).
>
> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in _system_sort_requirements() (line 2805 of /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.module).
>
> Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in _system_sort_requirements() (line 2805 of /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.module).
>
> Warning: usort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function in system_status() (line 2351 of
> /srv/bindings/00fd0ded5def4c8289075262cb552d75/code/modules/system/system.admin.inc).

Has anyone seen this before?  It's something to do with core but I have no idea what's caused it.

Comment: You need to provide more details ? Did you updated Drupal core ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this issue can occur if two modules return the same array key from `hook_requirements`?

Here's a similar result affecting LinkedIn Integration:

- [#1711604: On installation errors reported from system.module and system.admin.inc](https://www.drupal.org/node/1711604#comment-9306769)

According to that issue, this will happen if two separate modules add a requirements check with a key of `curl`. The solution is to namespace requirements checks (use a key of `linkedin_curl`, `simpletest_curl` and so forth).

You could debug this and check the issue queue for the affected module(s).

- Disabling the most recently added modules might help you identify the cause (see if the symptom goes away).
- If you still feel stuck and don't feel able to dig further, try updating your question with the list of enabled modules on your site. That may help narrow it down.
- If you're running all contrib modules, googling for "strcmp _system_sort_requirements drupal" might show results that help you identify the affected module.
- If you have Drush + Devel module, try `drush fn-hook requirements` to see which installed modules are implementing `hook_requirements`.
- Or just start hacking on your system settings page and trace the problem down old-school :)

If this is the cause, once you identify the module(s) causing the issue you should check the issue queue, file an issue if none already exists, and help be a part of getting it fixed!

I've tagged several affected modules in [#933684 - Same requirements from different modules causes warnings in _system_sort_requirements()](https://www.drupal.org/node/933684#comment-9744101)

Answer (score 0):

It was the SimplePie Core module, turning it off made the error go away.